# Top rows with sum of input

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have table something like below where user will give me one input of any quantity with product(e.g. Quantity - 5000 and Product - P001) then I have to give him in returns row wise data.. I mean in which Batch his quantity will fulfill and it should be date wise.. first to end

```
Batch       |Product  | Date               | Quantity  |
------------+---------+--------------------+-----------+
D001        |P001     | 1Jul2017           | 1000      |
D002        |P001     | 10Jul2017          | 2000      |
D003        |P001     | 15Jul2017          | 3000      |
D004        |P001     | 18Jul2017          | 5500      |
D005        |P002     | 12Jul2017          | 3000      |
D006        |P002     | 14Jul2017          | 2000      |
D007        |P002     | 15Jul2017          | 4000      |
```

And the final output should be something like.

```
Batch       |Product  | Date               | Quantity  |
------------+---------+--------------------+-----------+
D001        |P001     | 1Jul2017           | 1000      |
D002        |P001     | 10Jul2017          | 2000      |
D003        |P001     | 15Jul2017          | 2000      |
```

Comment: I have tried so many things but all waste thatswhy posted here

Comment: Why is Department  always D001 in the result set?

Comment: Edit the post please.

Comment: It would be hard to do in sql alone only. At least for me. If users need 100, and you have 50, 50, 100, so you go with 50,50 or 100? If user needs 100, but you have only 200, so you split or what?

Comment: It would be date wise if day1 -50, day2- 50 and day3 - 100 then they need records of day1 and day 2

Comment: Here his requirement has been fulfill with top 3 records but they give me input of 10000 then result would be something like below
Batch       |Product  | Date               | Quantity  |
------------+---------+--------------------+-----------+
D001        |P001     | 1Jul2017           | 1000      |
D002        |P001     | 10Jul2017          | 2000      |
D003        |P001     | 15Jul2017          | 3000      |
D004        |P001     | 18Jul2017          | 4000      |

Comment: Please edit the post

Comment: If you want something 'datewise', store dates, not malformatted strings.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want a cumulative sum.  Let's assume the quantity you want is in `@quantity`.  Then . . .

```
select t.*,
       (case when cume_q < @quantity then quantity
             else cume_q - @quantity
        end) as used_quantity
from (select t.*, (@q := @q + t.quantity) as cume_q
      from t cross join
           (select @q := 0) params
      where product = @product
      order by date
     ) t
where (cume_q - quantity) < @quantity;
```

The subquery calculates the cumulative sum.  You can run it separately and see what is happening.  If you want to learn about variables in MySQL, I refer you to do the documentation.

The outer `where` just chooses the rows that you want, once you have the cumulative sum.

Comment: didnt understand what is happening.. could you please make me understand